# C# Zoom In and Zoom Out On A Image

Tags: c#

I want to make a program have zoom in and zoom out function.(2x,4x,8x)But I can't use a available zoom function.I have to write a new one.I have done importing bitmap image.And I can get rgb color for each pixel.I created matrisses colorR,colorG and colorB for r,g and b colors.After that I thought I can create the 2x zoomed image with SolidBrush on a panel.I will draw 2x image like this:

**Original Image** (For example 3x3 pixels) (p=pixel color and "_" for space)

> p1_p2_p3
>
> p4_p5_p6
>
> p7_p8_p9

**2x Zoomed Image** (6x6 pixels because of orginal image size) (p=pixel color of orginal image and "_" for space)

> p1_p1_p2_p2_p3_p3
>
> p1_p1_p2_p2_p3_p3
>
> p4_p4_p5_p5_p6_p6
>
> p4_p4_p5_p5_p6_p6
>
> p7_p7_p8_p8_p9_p9
>
> p7_p7_p8_p8_p9_p9

I wrote one loop but it didn't work because it is complety wrong.So how can I write ***for*** loops ?

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();//insignificant
        listBox2.Items.Clear();//insignificant
        listBox3.Items.Clear();//insignificant

        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog()) {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp|*.*|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Graphics my2xImage = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpHeight, bmpWidth];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpHeight, bmpWidth];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpHeight, bmpWidth];



        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++) {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                colorR[x, y] = pixelColor.R;
                colorG[x, y] = pixelColor.G;
                colorB[x, y] = pixelColor.B;

                listBox1.Items.Add("(" + (x + 1) + "," + (y + 1) + ")" + " " + colorR[x, y]);//insignificant
                listBox2.Items.Add("(" + (x + 1) + "," + (y + 1) + ")" + " " + colorG[x, y]);//insignificant
                listBox3.Items.Add("(" + (x + 1) + "," + (y + 1) + ")" + " " + colorB[x, y]);//insignificant

            }

        }



        //for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight * 2); y++)
        //{
        //    for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth * 2); x++)
        //    {
        //        Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[x,y], colorG[x,y], colorB[x,y]);
        //        SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
        //        my2xImage.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
        //    }
        //}


    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is insane, but if you really *must* do it this way, then try something like this:

```
            int dx = x*2;
            int dy = y*2;

            colorR[dx  ,dy  ] = pixelColor.R;
            colorR[dx+1,dy  ] = pixelColor.R;
            colorR[dx  ,dy+1] = pixelColor.R;
            colorR[dx+1,dy+1] = pixelColor.R;

            colorG[dx  ,dy  ] = pixelColor.G;
            colorG[dx+1,dy  ] = pixelColor.G;
            colorG[dx  ,dy+1] = pixelColor.G;
            colorG[dx+1,dy+1] = pixelColor.G;

            colorB[dx  ,dy  ] = pixelColor.B;
            colorB[dx+1,dy  ] = pixelColor.B;
            colorB[dx  ,dy+1] = pixelColor.B;
            colorB[dx+1,dy+1] = pixelColor.B;
```

Comment: I tried your way.But it didn't work.I think it overwrites on matris.So the drawn image copy of the first image and the remaining pixels are black.Just like this: [link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161008/jzhf6sgi.jpg)

Comment: If the linked picture is what you did, then you did not try my way.  You tried some weird way of your own invention, but not my way.  My way is listed in my answer.  And it will work.  If you try it.

Comment: It seemed to me the same.I am looking for 10 minutes to understand how to write your way but I can't do it.How to get each pixel of image and how to set each pixel of 2x zoom in image ? Can you write in code please ? :(

Comment: Look at the code I have posted.  Look at your code.  Spot the differences.  Make your code look like my code.  Win.

Comment: I finally get it.So I win :) Thanks for your support.Now I can continue my project.Next step zoom in 4x,8x and zoom out 2x,4x,8x.I get the logic.Now easier to continue :) Thanks again.

Comment: Good, I am glad my answer was of use to you.  Do not forget to upvote any and all answers that were useful, and "accept" the one that was most useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DrawImage` method of the `Graphics` class.

```
Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpFirst);

// Draw image to screen.
g.DrawImage(newImage, destRect, x, y, width, height, units);
```

Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142045(v=vs.110).aspx

Look here also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e(v=vs.110).aspx

You can even set the interpolation mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode(v=vs.110).aspx

You are looking for the NearestNeighbor interpolation mode.

Comment: Thanks for links.But I don't know why I can't write e.Graphics.DrawImage(bla,bla,bla) part.I cant write e and put dot but only shows this commands:"Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString" Do you know why "Graphics" command didn't pops up ?

Comment: My bad. It should be `g.DrawImage ()`

Answer (score 0):

He is the solution.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e       )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();

        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp|*.*|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();




        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpHeight*2 , bmpWidth*2];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpHeight*2 , bmpWidth*2];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpHeight*2 , bmpWidth*2];



        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                int dx = x * 2;
                int dy = y * 2;

                colorR[dx, dy] = pixelColor.R;
                colorR[dx + 1, dy] = pixelColor.R;
                colorR[dx, dy + 1] = pixelColor.R;
                colorR[dx + 1, dy + 1] = pixelColor.R;

                colorG[dx, dy] = pixelColor.G;
                colorG[dx + 1, dy] = pixelColor.G;
                colorG[dx, dy + 1] = pixelColor.G;
                colorG[dx + 1, dy + 1] = pixelColor.G;

                colorB[dx, dy] = pixelColor.B;
                colorB[dx + 1, dy] = pixelColor.B;
                colorB[dx, dy + 1] = pixelColor.B;
                colorB[dx + 1, dy + 1] = pixelColor.B;




            }

        }



        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight*2); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth*2); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[x, y], colorG[x, y], colorB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gerax, on stackoverflow, copying other people's answers is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Why ? I didn't do nothing wrong.I write final code to somebody might be get help via google.And I can write this code because of  @Mike Nakis .You can read our conversations.Besides this is the solution code right ? How is this possible to wrote different way ? I wrote with using for loops but the same logic.Even I will write the revised solution here to everybody can see.But you are right about one point, I have to write "Mike Nakis" on my answer but anyway I have talked too much.Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***for loops*** for ***color[dx,dy]*** parts.Here it is for 8x zoom.

```
        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel3.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpHeight * 8, bmpWidth * 8];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpHeight * 8, bmpWidth * 8];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpHeight * 8, bmpWidth * 8];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                int dx = x * 8;
                int dy = y * 8;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        colorR[dx + j, dy + i] = pixelColor.R;
                        colorG[dx + j, dy + i] = pixelColor.G;
                        colorB[dx + j, dy + i] = pixelColor.B;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code (Also you can download project: [Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai9cAq3kwVDzg5oObjssgoG99E2vDQ)

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e       )
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;

        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp|*.jpg|*.jpg|*.*|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a image file.");
        }
        else
        {
            int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

            if (bmpHeight > 100 || bmpWidth > 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Image size can't be bigger than 100x100 pixels");
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth * 2 , bmpHeight *2];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth * 2 , bmpHeight *2];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth * 2 , bmpHeight *2];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                int dx = x * 2;
                int dy = y * 2;

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    {
                        colorR[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.R;
                        colorG[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.G;
                        colorB[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.B;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight*2); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth*2); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[x, y], colorG[x, y], colorB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel2.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth * 4, bmpHeight * 4];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth * 4, bmpHeight * 4];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth * 4, bmpHeight * 4];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                int dx = x * 4;
                int dy = y * 4;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    {
                        colorR[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.R;
                        colorG[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.G;
                        colorB[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.B;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight * 4); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth * 4); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[x, y], colorG[x, y], colorB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }

    }


    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel3.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth * 8, bmpHeight * 8];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth * 8, bmpHeight * 8];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth * 8, bmpHeight * 8];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                int dx = x * 8;
                int dy = y * 8;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        colorR[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.R;
                        colorG[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.G;
                        colorB[dx + i, dy + j] = pixelColor.B;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight * 8); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth * 8); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[x, y], colorG[x, y], colorB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage5;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel4.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                colorR[x, y] = pixelColor.R;

                colorG[x, y] = pixelColor.G;

                colorB[x, y] = pixelColor.B;

            }
        }

        int[,] colorSR = new int[bmpWidth /2, bmpHeight /2];
        int[,] colorSG = new int[bmpWidth /2, bmpHeight /2];
        int[,] colorSB = new int[bmpWidth /2, bmpHeight /2];

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpWidth / 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpHeight /2; j++)
            {
                colorSR[i, j] = (colorR[2 * i, 2 * j] + colorR[2 * i, 2 * j + 1] + colorR[2 * i + 1, 2 * j] + colorR[2 * i + 1, 2 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSG[i, j] = (colorG[2 * i, 2 * j] + colorG[2 * i, 2 * j + 1] + colorG[2 * i + 1, 2 * j] + colorG[2 * i + 1, 2 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSB[i, j] = (colorB[2 * i, 2 * j] + colorB[2 * i, 2 * j + 1] + colorB[2 * i + 1, 2 * j] + colorB[2 * i + 1, 2 * j + 1]) / 4;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight / 2); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth / 2); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorSR[x, y], colorSG[x, y], colorSB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage6;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel5.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                colorR[x, y] = pixelColor.R;
                colorG[x, y] = pixelColor.G;
                colorB[x, y] = pixelColor.B;

            }
        }

        int[,] colorSR = new int[bmpWidth / 4, bmpHeight / 4];
        int[,] colorSG = new int[bmpWidth / 4, bmpHeight / 4];
        int[,] colorSB = new int[bmpWidth / 4, bmpHeight / 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpWidth / 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpHeight / 4; j++)
            {
                colorSR[i, j] = (colorR[4 * i, 4 * j] + colorR[4 * i, 4 * j + 1] + colorR[4 * i + 1, 4 * j] + colorR[4 * i + 1, 4 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSG[i, j] = (colorG[4 * i, 4 * j] + colorG[4 * i, 4 * j + 1] + colorG[4 * i + 1, 4 * j] + colorG[4 * i + 1, 4 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSB[i, j] = (colorB[4 * i, 4 * j] + colorB[4 * i, 4 * j + 1] + colorB[4 * i + 1, 4 * j] + colorB[4 * i + 1, 4 * j + 1]) / 4;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight / 4); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth / 4); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorSR[x, y], colorSG[x, y], colorSB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage7;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel6.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                colorR[x, y] = pixelColor.R;
                colorG[x, y] = pixelColor.G;
                colorB[x, y] = pixelColor.B;

            }
        }

        int[,] colorSR = new int[bmpWidth / 8, bmpHeight / 8];
        int[,] colorSG = new int[bmpWidth / 8, bmpHeight / 8];
        int[,] colorSB = new int[bmpWidth / 8, bmpHeight / 8];

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpWidth / 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpHeight / 8; j++)
            {
                colorSR[i, j] = (colorR[8 * i, 8 * j] + colorR[8 * i, 8 * j + 1] + colorR[8 * i + 1, 8 * j] + colorR[8 * i + 1, 8 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSG[i, j] = (colorG[8 * i, 8 * j] + colorG[8 * i, 8 * j + 1] + colorG[8 * i + 1, 8 * j] + colorG[8 * i + 1, 8 * j + 1]) / 4;
                colorSB[i, j] = (colorB[8 * i, 8 * j] + colorB[8 * i, 8 * j + 1] + colorB[8 * i + 1, 8 * j] + colorB[8 * i + 1, 8 * j + 1]) / 4;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < (bmpHeight / 8); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (bmpWidth / 8); x++)
            {
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorSR[x, y], colorSG[x, y], colorSB[x, y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;

        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp|*.jpg|*.jpg|*.*|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a image file.");
        }
        else
        {

            int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

            if (bmpHeight > 800 || bmpWidth > 800)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Image size can't be bigger than 800x800 pixels.");
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = true;
                button6.Enabled = true;
                button7.Enabled = true;
                button10.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage8;

        int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

        Bitmap bmpFirst = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
        Graphics g = panel7.CreateGraphics();

        int[,] colorR = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorG = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];
        int[,] colorB = new int[bmpWidth, bmpHeight];

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = bmpFirst.GetPixel(x, y);

                colorR[x, y] = pixelColor.R;
                colorG[x, y] = pixelColor.G;
                colorB[x, y] = pixelColor.B;

            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < bmpHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bmpWidth; x++)
            {
                int dx = bmpWidth - 1;
                int dy = bmpHeight - 1;
                Color mySpecialColor = Color.FromArgb(colorR[dx - x, dy - y], colorG[dx - x, dy - y], colorB[dx - x, dy - y]);
                SolidBrush pixelBrush = new SolidBrush(mySpecialColor);
                g.FillRectangle(pixelBrush, x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;

        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "*.bmp|*.bmp|*.jpg|*.jpg|*.*|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }

        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a image file.");
        }
        else
        {
            int bmpHeight = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            int bmpWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;

            if (bmpHeight > 800 || bmpWidth > 800)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Image size can't be bigger than 800x800 pixels");
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                button6.Enabled = false;
                button7.Enabled = false;
                button10.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```